# GRUB won't detect windows 10 custom menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

After Installing Linux, GRUB won't detect windows 10 at all, I tried all the other methods; mounting and grub-install and so on. Since I was able to boot into windows using the Windows Boot Manager from the one-time boot menu, I decided to use the custom menu entry thing. However when I specify the C:/ Drive using the following :

```
menuentry "Windows 10 - BOOT" {
set root='(hd0,5)'
chainloader +1
}
```

and try to enter, a grey screen appears saying Windows was not able to boot properly.

Also I know the location of the Boot Manager thing by using the cmd command `bcedit` (or something). Is there a way I can directly link to that location? Or what else can I do? Please note: Windows boots fine using the windows manager. Grub just wont identify it.

FDISK -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5F0BE615-5AFA-4406-BF4C-CCE5B3AB75D0

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1026048   1107967     81920    40M unknown
/dev/sda3    1107968   1370111    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1370112   2394111   1024000   500M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5    2394112 914409471 912015360 434.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  914409472 915331071    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  915331072 976771071  61440000  29.3G Microsoft basic data
```

Comment: As a temporary fix (will not solve the problem, but will allow you to boot to Windows), upon boot you can open the BIOS boot menu (exact key combination to do this will vary; if you don't know it, Google it ;) and choose Windows, and that will allow you to boot into Windows. If that doesn't work, then you _know_ Windows is broken.

Comment: @Nonny Yes, That's what I'm doing I have a dell laptop which on legacy mode allows a one time boot menu using (f12). However this is not a personal laptop and I don't really expect other users to understand the situation and use this temp fix.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much. I was just trying to help in the meantime. :)

If you do that, does Windows boot properly?

Comment: As above. And you need to read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI , understand what you did wrong with the Ubuntu installation and why you don't use the method you tried with UEFI.

Comment: @Nonny Yes, Windows works absolutely fine this way.

Comment: @CelticWarrior The method I tried with UEFI you mean with /dev/sda1? It says no operating system found if I do that.

Comment: Please read and understand how to do a dual boot in UEFI. The method you used that didn't work (it couldn't) is not applicable.